Change ASP.NET Core application configuration sources order of precedence
I understand what the default order of preference is for ASP.NET Core as mentioned here MS Docs | Default application configuration sources. However I would like to know if it is possible to change this order?
In my scenario, all app settings are defined as Env variables in a deployment.yaml manifest which is stored in a remote manifests repo used by a GitOps operator (ArgoCD) to deploy the application.
However, when working on a feature branch, I want to be able to override those env settings with the appsettings.preview.json file that is in the app source code repo, thus avoiding changes in the app manifest repo when working on features.  Changes to that remote repo will only be done when testing is complete and we can define the required values in the env variables of the deployment.yaml manifest.
I was planning to deploy the feature branch version with ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Preview and only change the order based on this value being set.

Sure, you can change the order of providers by clearing configuration sources and adding them back in an order that suits you best. But what is stopping you from simply adding another configuration source for appsettings.preview.json file since values from that file would take precedence over values from deployment.yaml manifest?

Oh, that sounds a lot simpler! So I can just conditionally add builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.preview.json");
I just found a reference to this behaviour in this section json-configuration-provider

I suggest you could consider check the environment firstly and manually add the config appsetting.json file as below:
var env = builder.Environment;

if (env.EnvironmentName == "Preview")
{
    builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.preview.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

}
else
{
    builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

}


Thank you, I have just tried this out and it works. I didn't realise that adding an extra AddJsonFile() call would just add onto the existing precedence order and therefore be the preferred. I don't think that the else block is required, but thanks!
